# Sum the amount and then delete the second row when its duplicate in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, duplicates

I am trying to do below two things for this table.

[image]

1. There are 3 Unique row if we check by EMP_Id, Year and Type. I need to add sum of Bonus_Amt only when it is duplicate. For ex, 
   For EMP_ID = 1708301 Bonus_AMT should be = 22196 + 3036.
   It should not do anything for EMP_ID = 642416.
2. Once the sum is done delete the second row but do check carefully that Bonus_Amt should be less then other one in duplicate record.

The table record should be like below when step 1 and step 2 is performed.

[image]

I did try something like below for Point 1 but this is giving me row number 2 and not row number 1. If i change t.rn = 1 then it is picking all records even the one which is not duplicate.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT o.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.EMP_Id ORDER BY o.Year) rn
     FROM Emp_Stat o where o.Year='2018' AND o.Type= 'Check' 
     ) t 
WHERE t.rn  > 1
```

Here UniqueId  does not matter. The catch is that only the record which is duplicate should be sum and then the one which is not added should be deleted. Also there is a column lst_update_time which should update to sysdate only for the duplicate row and not for any other record.

Comment: How do you decide which Unique_id should remain after deletion? Or does it not matter?

Comment: It does not matter. The catch is that only the record which is duplicate should be sum and then the one which is not added should be deleted. Also there is a column lst_update_time which should update to sysdate only for the duplicate row and not for any other record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a single MERGE statement, using both update and delete in the `when matched` clause, like so:

```
merge into t1 tgt
  using (select unique_id,
                emp_id,
                sum(bonus_amt) over (partition by emp_id, year, type) new_bonus_amt,
                year,
                type,
                count(*) over (partition by emp_id, year, type) grp_count,
                row_number() over (partition by emp_id, year, type order by bonus_amt desc) rn
         from   t1) src
  on (tgt.unique_id = src.unique_id and src.grp_count > 1)
when matched then
   update set tgt.bonus_amt = src.new_bonus_amt,
              tgt.last_update_time = sysdate
   delete where rn != 1;
```

[Demo DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e1287d405f92582ab36499fa5cc4faae)

This works by finding the sum of the bonus_amt for each group (doesn't matter if the group has a single row or multiple) and identifying the first row in the group (that is, the one with the highest bonus_amt), so we know which row to keep.

Then, the we use that source set of data in the merge statement to update the bonus_amt of every row (you need to update every row, otherwise the delete won't "see" the un-updated rows) before deleting all but the first row in each group.

Comment: This query is good but its my bad i didn't mention entire requirement. There is Last_Update_Time column also. Problem is that if i add set Last_Update_Time=sysdate  in update line it will update all row despite its duplicate or not. Adding rn != 1 will not help either because it will update second row and then in delete it will remove it.... Can you advice on this please.. I need to update the timestamp of duplicate one only.

Comment: Does it matter if all the rows have their last_update_time amended if the duplicate rows are going to be deleted anyway? Or are you saying that you don't want the duplicated rows to be deleted after all?

Comment: There are duplicate and then unique records also in this table. Only row with duplicate row should have there last_update_time updated and not the Unique record one and Yes, for audit purpose it lst_updt_time does matter.  As per the solution provided it is updating other column and deleting the one which is duplicate.. this is correct only thing missing is last_update_time for duplicate rows only.

Comment: I would have thought that for audit purposes, you'd need to know that the unique row was also updated? I.e. update the last_update_time column for all rows, given you're updating the bonus_amt for all rows?

Comment: Oh, hangon - you're saying that you want to ignore rows where there is only a single row in the group?

Comment: yes, but unique row bonus_amount is not getting updated .. Only update should be for duplicate row hence the need to for updating lst_update_time for duplicate row only. Thanks in advance for the help though.

Comment: Oh, hangon - you're saying that you want to ignore rows where there is only a single row in the group?   YES

Comment: Ok, I've updated both my answer (to include a count of the group, so that we only merge where the count is > 1), and the dbfiddle demo.

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer with merge statement;
Just wanted to suggest more transparent solution :

1. Start
2. Select sum grouped by the UK (as in that merge statement) and insert results into the auxiliary table. - You will have one record per UK
3. Delete ALL records from the base table
4. Insert into base table from aux .table
5. commit work;